# Visual Studio debugger showing variables with memory address instead of value

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I recently moved to a new PC, and my visual studio is now showing all variables in some sort of memory address mode.  Normally I would just see the simple properties and values.  I can't figure out how to turn this off and get the standard view.

[Visual Studio Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDUmA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aw dude, so simple:

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio
2. Right-click on the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 shortcut and go to its Properties
3. Go to the Compatibility tab and uncheck "Run this program in compatible mode for:" and say Apply

Now start Visual Studio and open the project. You should be able to debug it.

Comment: For what it's worth, here are some links that led me there:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d3e003fc-1517-4a5a-a123-c994cf16c864/visual-studio-debugger-shows-hexadecimal-values-for-everything-and-error-does-not-exists-when?forum=vsdebug

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fc92bce7-30f0-4436-a25c-53b21f873aa6/debugging-c-aspnet-project-treats-project-as-ccli-instead-of-c?forum=vsdebug